# Why isn't After ordering correctly?

Tags: systemd

My docker.prom.service unit file has:

```
After=docker.service media-data.mount
```

media-data.mount has a chain of:

```
media-data.mount +280ms
└─remote-fs-pre.target @2.116s
  └─rpcbind.service @2.261s +13ms
    └─rpcbind.socket @1.549s
      └─sysinit.target @1.534s
        └─apparmor.service @1.349s +168ms
          └─local-fs.target @1.346s
            └─var-lib-docker-aufs-mnt-fd982b7186fd056a83f57948112a542ac04a6b161e58fdde16fe3191f7279915.mount @6.882s
              └─local-fs-pre.target @678ms
                └─lvm2-monitor.service @417ms +250ms
                  └─lvm2-lvmetad.service @558ms
                    └─system.slice @277ms
                      └─-.slice @235ms
```

docker.prom.service has a chain of:

```
docker.prom.service @5.483s
└─docker.service @1.976s +3.491s
  └─network-online.target @1.974s
    └─network.target @1.972s
      └─networking.service @1.533s +436ms
        └─apparmor.service @1.349s +168ms
          └─local-fs.target @1.346s
            └─var-lib-docker-aufs-mnt-fd982b7186fd056a83f57948112a542ac04a6b161e58fdde16fe3191f7279915.mount @6.882s
              └─local-fs-pre.target @678ms
                └─lvm2-monitor.service @417ms +250ms
                  └─lvm2-lvmetad.service @558ms
                    └─system.slice @277ms
                      └─-.slice @235ms
```

I would expect to see media-data.mount in the critical chain of docker.prom.service since media-data.mount is explicitly called out in the After= line of the docker.prom.service file.

Am I missing something obvious?